# How to paint over wires showing through plaster

Tags: electrical, paint

We have had some new electrical work but the wires have not been chased very deeply into the walls, they are covered in a little plaster. As you can see from the pictures no amount of coats of paint seem to be hiding them.

We have tried a zinsser BIN primer, multiple coats of top coat.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not know the electric code in the UK/Europe, but imagine the best choice would be to have the person back and make the chase deeper into the plaster, they made a mistake.  It looks like the black of the wire/cable is bleeding though.  It takes many coats of primer/top coat to cover a dark colour on a lighter colour wall.

Comment: @crip659 - this is poor advice, which I have clarified in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Converting from comment</sup>

Regarding other comments/answers - if the finish is flat, then the chase is acceptable by UK regs. It is not necessary to bury a cable at any given depth, nor even cover or conduit it. It's expected that cables will run up or down from any given socket & it's caveat emptor for anyone hammering nails into it afterwards.

It's a matter of finding something that won't bleed the darker colour, unless it's just a matter of drying times, which you can't tell from a photo. I've never known colour bleed from a cable… nor in fact ever seen a black twin & earth. They're mid-grey… about the same colour as the majority of the wall, by coincidence.

You might want to give it a couple of weeks to make certain the plaster's dry, then either give the B-I-N another go, or swap to Zinsster's 'Cover Stain' which is a solvent-base, not a shellac.

Comment: Cheers, will have to try out a different primer/sealer as you say.. the cables arnt black I think it is just how they appear in the photograph. The best solution would be to have the chase cut deeper, but that is not ideal. This is my mums house and I don’t think they want anymore disruption. This is essentially all of the wires in 3 downstairs rooms. A paint solution is the preferred option.

Answer (score 1):

You need a primer which will not dissolve the stain.
You've tried BIN which is shellac primer and it didn't work,
and I'm guessing latex acrylic paint,  try an oil-based primer.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it suggested to wait 1-2 weeks before applying a second coat of stain blocking primer due to curing.